# Changing the field appearance after making enable = "false" to that field?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to make enabled="false" to one form field in my flex application. But the appearance of the field after disabling it 
is looking furious. I want to change the look  of the field after disabling it in my way. So can i change the look and feel of a field after disabling it ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write a `skin` for your component.

Every skin has different `states` for skinning. In your case, you have to write skin for `disabled` state.

To get started, this tutorial might be useful - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html

For detailed information on skinning, please visit http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Concept: -
Use constraint based layout concept.
If you are using actionscript use move()

```
Ex: - 
button.move(100,100);
if(button.visible)
{
    button1.move(button.x + button.height + 5,button.y);
}

so on....
```

Please add some code so that we can suggest what exactly you are looking for.